# integrated facebook facepile need

Tags: facebook, facepile

I am working on project, it needs [facepile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile/) (plugin of facebook) in index page,

how can I do it?

Comment: [facepile was abandoned](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile/)

Answer (score 2):

you need to get an appID from facebook developers site. (http://developers.facebook.com/setup/)

then..

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: 'YOUR APP ID HERE', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});
};
(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

THEN...

place this into your page:

```
<fb:friendpile width="210"></fb:friendpile>
```

or whatever feature you need.

try this link for more: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Is this showing the Facepile of a page or the user himself (me)?

I tried your code but it always shows a login frame also if I'm already logged in to Facebook.

My target is to have a list of Fans and posts of a specific page for my website.